# how to update ng-model of textarea after manual insert of some text into it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code which takes input from an input area and inserts the text at the caret position inside a text area, the insert part is working accurately but ng-model of text area fails to update the same. here is the code

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.add = function() {
    $scope.items.push($scope.someInput);
    $rootScope.$broadcast('add', $scope.someInput);
  }
});

app.directive('myText', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $rootScope.$on('add', function(e, val) {
        var domElement = element[0];

        if (document.selection) {
          domElement.focus();
          var sel = document.selection.createRange();
          sel.text = val;
          domElement.focus();
        } else if (domElement.selectionStart || domElement.selectionStart === 0) {
          var startPos = domElement.selectionStart;
          var endPos = domElement.selectionEnd;
          var scrollTop = domElement.scrollTop;
          domElement.value = domElement.value.substring(0, startPos) + val + domElement.value.substring(endPos, domElement.value.length);
          domElement.focus();
          domElement.selectionStart = startPos + val.length;
          domElement.selectionEnd = startPos + val.length;
          domElement.scrollTop = scrollTop;
        } else {
          domElement.value += val;
          domElement.focus();
        }

      });
    }
  }
}])
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <input ng-model="someInput">
      <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
      <p ng-repeat="item in items">Created {{ item }}</p>  
    </div>
    <p>add some text and change caret position and insert test using input area above</p>
    <textarea my-text="" ng-model="textarea">
    </textarea>
    <p>{{textarea}}</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest fix to your code that I can think of is added below.  Basically, require the ng-model controller into your directive, and inform it when the value has changed.

A little off-topic, but having your myText directive be controlled via global scope (in the form of $rootScope.$on) smells bad to me.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.add = function() {
    $scope.items.push($scope.someInput);
    $rootScope.$broadcast('add', $scope.someInput);
  }
});

app.directive('myText', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    require: '^ngModel', // request our containing ng-model controller
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) { // DI
      $rootScope.$on('add', function(e, val) {
        var domElement = element[0];

        if (document.selection) {
          domElement.focus();
          var sel = document.selection.createRange();
          sel.text = val;
          domElement.focus();
        } else if (domElement.selectionStart || domElement.selectionStart === 0) {
          var startPos = domElement.selectionStart;
          var endPos = domElement.selectionEnd;
          var scrollTop = domElement.scrollTop;
          domElement.value = domElement.value.substring(0, startPos) + val + domElement.value.substring(endPos, domElement.value.length);
          domElement.focus();
          domElement.selectionStart = startPos + val.length;
          domElement.selectionEnd = startPos + val.length;
          domElement.scrollTop = scrollTop;
        } else {
          domElement.value += val;
          domElement.focus();
        }
        // inform ng-model that the value has changed
        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(domElement.value);
      });
    }
  }
}])
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <input ng-model="someInput">
      <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
      <p ng-repeat="item in items">Created {{ item }}</p>  
    </div>
    <p>add some text and change caret position and insert test using input area above</p>
    <textarea my-text="" ng-model="textarea">
    </textarea>
    <p>{{textarea}}</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: No I am not using rootscope, its just a quick example I put up, instead of posting the huge code.

Comment: and yes sir, it does fix it

Comment: however, you might consider actually setting the scope-variable in javascript, as this automatically digests the changes. see my answer

Answer (score 0):

There is actually not much too change in your code. You just don't make use of the $scope, resp. $rootScope variable correctly. If you update the $rootScope variable $rootScope.textarea instead of domElement.value, angular does all the "magic" binding for you ;-)

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.add = function() {
    $scope.items.push($scope.someInput);
    $rootScope.$broadcast('add', $scope.someInput);
  }
});

app.directive('myText', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $rootScope.$on('add', function(e, val) {
        var domElement = element[0];

        if (document.selection) {
          domElement.focus();
          var sel = document.selection.createRange();
          sel.text = val;
          domElement.focus();
        } else if (domElement.selectionStart || domElement.selectionStart === 0) {
          var startPos = domElement.selectionStart;
          var endPos = domElement.selectionEnd;
          var scrollTop = domElement.scrollTop;
          $rootScope.textarea = domElement.value.substring(0, startPos) + val + domElement.value.substring(endPos, domElement.value.length);
          domElement.focus();
          domElement.selectionStart = startPos + val.length;
          domElement.selectionEnd = startPos + val.length;
          domElement.scrollTop = scrollTop;
        } else {
           $rootScope.textarea += val;
          domElement.focus();
        }

      });
    }
  }
}])
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <input ng-model="someInput">
      <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
      <p ng-repeat="item in items">Created {{ item }}</p>  
    </div>
    <p>add some text and change caret position and insert test using input area above</p>
    <textarea my-text="" ng-model="textarea">
    </textarea>
    <p>{{textarea}}</p>
  </body>

</html>
```